# Proget Package Identification - how to publish same package (and version) but different .net framework?

Tags: .net, proget

we're using [proget](https://inedo.com/support/documentation/proget/overview) for our packages, and we'd like to support two different .net framework targets for one package (with the same name and version).

according to the [docs](https://inedo.com/support/documentation/proget/core-concepts/packages#package-id) Package Identification is unique by its name and version, but i couldn't find any clue how to change/configure it.

is it possible to publish two packages under the same name and version but each one is targeted to different .net framework ? and how ?

The goal is to have two consumer-projects, each in different .net framework, and both of them is using the same dependency package(same version), without bothering each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Framework multi-targeting is handled inside of the NuGet package itself, and by the NuGet client (either nuget.exe or Visual Studio) upon extraction. Take a look at Microsoft's documentation for more information on how to create a package with multiple targets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks

But to answer the general question of "*is it possible to publish two packages under the same name and version*", the answer to that is "*you can't*" because the name and version are the unique identifier.